# Does Google own Android apps that I post on Google Play?

Tags: copyright, software, licensing

Does Google own the apps or the app content that I post on Google Play? Do they copyright my code and content, or am I the owner and responsible for providing any copyrights.

Comment: what you mean for "providing any copyrights"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have the copyright of your work and grant to Google a nonexclusive, worldwide, and royalty-free license to reproduce, perform, display, analyze, and use the App as well as to distribute it.